# How to draw a character in a similar art style to this?

Tags: color, games, character

I'm trying to achieve the quality of this art style. However I'm not a professional artist yet. Still practicing and have a long way to go.

[image]

Now I have made a rough sketch, outlined it, colored and removed the strokes. 2nd image is my poor drawings :)

My 1st question: Is it the right way to go with outlines since the referenced character has a flat art style feel to it?

2nd question what is the next step after removing the outline? So I thought picking up the eraser and reshaping the colors but that somehow seems to contradict the purpose of having outlines in the first place.. And wouldn't this be double work?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I voted to close this as "too broad". I understand where you're questioning things. But really, there are *no rules* for illustration. There may be some "tricks" which work well for some, but then fail miserably for others. The long and short of it is that answers would merely be how one particular person creates *their* artwork. i.e. their *opinion* on what works well. Which may have value, but in order to fully elaborate on a technique, I feel it would take a small novella. Making this too broad. If you could narrow the scope of your question, it may be better, at least to me.

Comment: In short, whatever works for you simply **works** and is *never* "wrong" if you find a method better for your creation.

Comment: I would advice you to start coloring it in right after the blue sketch and color it using a brush. Skip the other steps. Maybe you didn't bucket fill the colors, but that's what it sort of looks like. Obviously, your image is missing shadows too. Your last image could also be transformed to look like the reference, but I would skip the line-art.